# Getting results from 2 consecutive queries (PHP, SQL)

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I need to return data from 2 separate tables at the same time. The info I need from the 2nd table is determined by what is returned from the first table. Here's what I'm working with..

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pending WHERE paymentid = '".$_GET['vnum']."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = @mysql_num_rows($result);

$linkid = $res['paymentid'];

if ($num==0) {
echo "Hello, ".$_SESSION['Fname']."<br />There was an error, I cannot find this payment in the records.";
} else {

$picquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _uploads_log WHERE linkid = '".$linkid."'");
$numb = @mysql_num_rows($picquery);
if ($numb==0) {
echo "there is no picture"; }
else {
echo "<img src=\"".$res['log_filename']."\" width=\"100\">"; }
```

I don't understand how to return the results as an array, if $res[] returns the results for the first query, then what returns the results for the second one?

or is there a better way to do this entirely?

Thank you

Comment: I /think/ you should be looking into SQL JOINs.

Comment: First of all, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Secondly, never ignore errors and warnings that may happen. On debug mode display the, on release mode log them and show `500 error` to users. BTW, to get an array retrieved from db: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_of_mysql_query_function)) $rows[] = $row;`

Comment: You store the result array as $result = mysql_query($query); and try to retrieve data from $res['paymentid'] ? same thing in second query.Also better to use inner query for this kind of fetch.

Comment: @pbl you stopped reading as soon as you saw the @. I'm aware that $res returns the array but it only returns the array from the first query.. the entire problem revolves around there being 2 queries.

Comment: second query result you storing in the $picquery variable it should contain the second array result. is that your problem ?

Comment: @HiggsBoson i think your problem is a bit further. Read more about SQL Injection. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a join, but in order to still get results from your first query even if there is no picture (I assume that's why you split it up) you want a left join.

select * from pending left join _uploads_log on pending.paymentID=$_GET['vnum'] and _uploads_log.linkid = pending.paymentID

(note: php markings removed for readability - you'll have to add them back in)

This should (untested since I don't have your tables) return the full row for your vnum variable and also include the picture data if there is one.

Comment: and pray query will not contains ambiguous columns.

Comment: that would be prevented by appending the table name to the column as I did above. Any repeated or accidentally duplicated column names not used in the query logic would both be shown in a join result

Comment: i have been trying to avoid using join but i think it's gonna be my only option. thanks, well done.